# Adding non-text files to `_posts` in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

Short story: **I want to be able to store non-text files/directories in the `_posts/` folder.**

This is not about local assets, or anything like that. I literally just want to store files (non-associated images and directories) there for a specific, unrelated issue that doesn't merit discussion.

**Is there a way to put a folder in `_posts/` and in essence have Jekyll ignore all of its contents?**  Or at least, not freak out about the contents being non-text files?

<s>**EDIT**: It seems that the actual errors are coming from the names of some of the sub-subdirectories. When the name of these directories start with a date, it gives me the error:</s>

`Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in /Users/burchill/burchill.github.io/_posts/blah/source/2017-1‌​0-28-blahblah_post/b‌​lah.png`

**EDIT #2**: After changing the directory names to "play nice" with Jekyll's regex, Jekyll no longer gives an error, but when I try to link to these images on my posts, they don't show up, unlike files in other non-`_posts` directories.

Comment: Could you list the directories you want jekyll to ignore in the `exclude` option in `_config.yml`?

Comment: I've tried that, but then the files don't show up when I try to link to them in posts.  The same thing happens when I change the subdirectories' names so they don't cause errors.

Answer (score -1):

Jekyll won't process files not starting with the triple dashes block (frontmatter) so it is safe to have any other file in your `_posts` folder.

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/

Comment: Hmmm, so it seems like the issue I'm having has something to do with the names of the subdirectories.  When I change the subdirectories' names so that they don't start with dates, it ends up working, but otherwise I get the error:
 Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in /Users/burchill/burchill.github.io/_posts/blah/source/2017-10-28-blahblah_post/blah.png.

Can I not name directories in certain ways?

Comment: You can't name your directories similar to how a "post" would be named because Jekyll uses regex on the path basename to identify it as a post.

Comment: But even after changing the directory names to "play nice" with Jekyll's regex, when I try to link to these images on my posts, they don't show up (but Jekyll doesn't crash). This isn't true of linking to files in other non-`_posts` directories.